# Passing local variables between methods (Node js, prototype)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, prototype

I have 2 methods

```
var variable_to_be_passed; // setting this does not seem to work

A.prototype.beforeEach = function(callback) {
  variable_to_be_passed = 5;
  ParentA.prototype.beforeEach.call(this, test, function() {
  callback();
});

A.prototype.afterEach = function(variable_to_be_passed, callback) {
  console.log(variable_to_be_passed) //prints undefined
  ParentA.prototype.afterEach.call(this, test, function() {
  callback();
});
```

I want to access variable_to_be_passed in A.prototype.aftereach. Could someone suggest how this should be done?

Thanks

Comment: Just remove it from the parameter list of `afterEach`

Comment: Please give an example on how these functions would be called on an `A` instance, and show us what the `ParentA` methods do if relevant.